# Have trouble with a CSS selector

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

I can't seem to get the css selector right for this:

```
<p ng-bind-html="hotelItem.details.allDetails.policyCancellationInstructions" class="ng-binding">
<div>To cancel this reservation <a href="https://www.getaroom.com/reservations?signature=57c685104ad3fe1525f17d0f54f2bde23ec82596&amp;utm_campaign=Affiliate&amp;utm_medium=cpa&amp;utm_source=studentuniverse.com">click here</a>. If you have questions regarding your booking contact Getaroom's customer care team: United States Customers: <a href="tel:+18002603895">800-260-3895</a>; United Kingdom Customers: <a href="tel:+08000124507">0800-012-4507</a></div> 
</p>
```

I've tried this to no avail:

```
'span[ng-bind-html="hotelItem.details.allDetails.policyCancellationInstructions"] > div'
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Provided HTML sample is for `p` node (without child, without closing tag) while CSS selector is for `span`. Share exact HTML

Comment: the css selector you have written contains div , share the html for that. Though I agree with @Andersson

Comment: updated original post

Comment: @PeterCook Quite clear you want a `css-selector` but exactly which element? What do you want to do next? Extract some `text`? Which text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the HTML you have shared :

for getting **div** (which really does not make any sense)

```
body div:nth-child(2)
```

For p node :

```
p[ng-bind-html*='policyCancellationInstructions']
```

For clicking on click here **link**  :

```
a[href*='https://www.getaroom.com']
```

I would highly suggest you to use **linkText** in this case.

For clicking on this number **800-260-3895**  :

```
a[href*='18002603895']
```

and for clicking on this number **0800-012-4507**:

```
a[href*='8000124507']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below CSS selector

```
body > div:nth-child(2)
```